# Passing data from Flask to Vue without requesting it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a universal and modular single page app with Vue that doesn't have any hardcoded IP addresses for requests to the backend (Flask) so it can be used with any backend without changing the source code and recompiling it.

Is it possible to pass data (in this case the IP and the port that the backend is running on) from the backend to the frontend without the frontend asking for it? If the frontend has to make a request for initial app data, it would already need a hardcoded IP address to the backend, defeating the purpose of what I'm trying to do.

I was thinking something along the lines of passing data (address of the backend) from the backend to the frontend while rendering the frontend, then collecting the address in the frontend and use it to make further requests to the backend.

I'm pretty new to VueJS and Flask so I'm just being curious. I also tried googling but didn't find anything - probably because I don't know how to phrase the problem correctly.

Is such a thing even possible or am I living in a dream world?

Comment: Any implementations will require at least an initial endpoint from which your frontend will get API information. once you feed that initial API address, you could use one of many schema API documentation packages (Swagger, for ex), to provide your client with full documentation about the available endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass data (in this case the IP and the port that the backend is running on) from the backend to the frontend without the frontend asking for it?

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <!-- this script makes eg. the "api" variable available globally -->
   <script src="./api_urls.js"/>
 </head>
</html>
```

Then in the static files **OF THE FRONTEND** - next to index.html add this file: (don't host this file on your backend - since this is against what you're asking)

```
// api_urls.js
window.api = { url: 'https://192.168.31.35:8080' }
```

Then in your Vue app you could do eg.

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    puppy: null,
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get(`${window.api.url}/api/puppies/123`)
     .then(data => { this.puppy = data.response }
  }
}
</script>
```

or you could just use window.api.url when creating your Axios instance then

---

If you had an API url injected from `process.env.VUE_APP_API` - so hardcoded - which is what you're trying to avoid, you'd have to update the env files then run `npm run build`.

With the above apprach though, you can just go to the folder that has the static files (`index.html` etc.), edit `api_urls.js`, save, and whoever visits the site will instantly send requests to the new URL.

---

I assume there's some security implications here though. If somebody used XSS to replace `window.api` to `{ api: 'https://evilwebiste.com/muhahaha'}` your users would send their passwords and logins to that website. I remember my architect saying that we have a strict content security policy (browser feature) that'd prevent something like this. Can't say much more.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I was so frustrated with the complicated nature of JS frameworks that I didn't even think of this simple solution.
I plan to only use the app locally and without any input fields so the security implications shouldn't be a big problem. It's a simple GUI for a simple RPi project.